# Does OAuth always use the HTTP Authorization header?

Tags: oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-iap

Have an app running in GCP using App Engine and secured by IAP. To the best of my knowledge IAP uses OAuth, but when I open the app in the browser and inspect the outgoing XHR requests I don't see the HTTP Authorization header on any of them. There does appear to be a token in the cookies though, something named GCP_IAAP_AUTH_TOKEN.
Just wondering if this is still considered OAuth or is it some other form of authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud IAP can use either the cookie `GCP_IAAP_AUTH_TOKEN` or `Authorization: Bearer`. Both are derived from OAuth2.

> The credential that Cloud IAP relies on is an OpenID Connect (OIDC)
>   token. That token can come from either a cookie `GCP_IAAP_AUTH_TOKEN`
>   or an `Authorization: bearer header`.

[Authenticating with OpenID Connect](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/getting-started-with-cloud-identity-aware-proxy)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know by any chance what scope I should specify for authenticating?

Comment: It depends on what permissions you need. To get started use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`. Reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

Comment: Thanks! One other question, do you know if it'd be possible to use the Google API Client libraries to invoke it programmaticly?

Comment: Here are some how-to guides to get you started https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/how-to